# GLSL Uniform Struct Array only Defines first Element

Tags: java, opengl, glsl

I've recently started programming a new 3D game and started importing models from blender and their associated .mtl files. I created a system for loading a model with multiple materials in the same mesh by assigning an index to each primitive and then accessing a material struct from a uniform array with said index. Strangely enough, this works for the 0th index but for any index higher than that it fails.

If I switch the (in this case) two materials then only the one assigned to the 0th index is render (excluding the possibility of my values being wrong). I checked all of the uniform locations and none of them are negative so that shouldn't be the issue either.

The shader code:

```
#version 400 core

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

in vec3 passVertex[];
in int passMtlIndex[]; // I don't have actual per-primitive values but I just use the first index in the array

out vec4 color;

struct Material {
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
    float dissolve;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 position;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

const int MAX_MATERIALS = 10;

uniform Material materials[MAX_MATERIALS];
uniform Light light;

void doVertex(int index, vec4 baseColor) {
    gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(passVertex[index], 1.0);
    color = baseColor;
    EmitVertex();
}

mat4 inverseAffine(mat4 matrix) {
    return mat4(
            matrix[0].x, matrix[1].x, matrix[2].x, 0,
            matrix[0].y, matrix[1].y, matrix[2].y, 0,
            matrix[0].z, matrix[1].z, matrix[2].z, 0,
            -dot(matrix[3].xyz, matrix[0].xyz), -dot(matrix[3].xyz, matrix[1].xyz), -dot(matrix[3].xyz, matrix[2].xyz), 1);
}

void main() {
    vec3 toEye = normalize(inverseAffine(view)[3].xyz - passVertex[0]);
    vec3 norm = normalize(cross(passVertex[1] - passVertex[0], passVertex[2] - passVertex[0]));
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - passVertex[0]);

    Material material = materials[passMtlIndex[0]];

    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * material.ambient;

    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.2);
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * (diff * material.diffuse);

    float spec = pow(max(dot(reflect(-lightDir, norm), toEye), 0.0), material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * (spec * material.specular);

    vec4 baseColor = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, material.dissolve);

    doVertex(0, baseColor);
    doVertex(1, baseColor);
    doVertex(2, baseColor);

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Rendering code:

```
// use program
shader.loadMaterial("materials[0]", grassMtl);
shader.loadMaterial("materials[1]", dirtMtl);
// render
```

Shader code:

```
public void loadMaterial(String name, Material value) {
    loadVector(name + ".ambient", value.getAmbient());
    loadVector(name + ".diffuse", value.getDiffuse());
    loadVector(name + ".specular", value.getSpecular());
    loadFloat(name + ".shininess", value.getShininess());
    loadFloat(name + ".dissolve", value.getDissolve());
}

public void loadVector(String name, Vector3f value) {
    GL20.glUniform3f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, name), value.x, value.y, value.z);
}

public void loadFloat(String name, float value) {
    GL20.glUniform1f(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(programID, name), value);
}
```

EDIT:
I have actually tried to just pass two separate materials into the shader and this works just fine but for some reason the array is still not working.

I also tried converting the array from a struct array to five arrays containing al of the members of the struct but that yields the same results (only the first element defined)

Also, how could I improve the line: `Material material = materials[passMtlIndex[0]];`? I've heard that index with a variable index is not recommended and slows down the GPU.

It seems to me that every time this question has been asked (and it has, in some shape or form), it's either been ignored or a suboptimal solution was found.

Comment: What do you mean by *"It seems to me that every time this question has been asked (and it has, in some shape or form), it's either been ignored or a suboptimal solution was found."*? Is this a duplicate question? Is `passMtlIndex[0]` a valid index? Does it work if you do `materials[0]` or `materials[1]`? Comes `passMtlIndex` from an integral attribute? how do you define the array of vertex attribute data? `glVertexAttribPointer` or `glVertexAttribIPointer` (focus on the `I` in the middle)?

Comment: OpenGL in java doesn't actually have that function. I have fixed the problem. It turns out the integer values that I passed into the vertex shader were somehow changed, so I just used floats instead and cast them to integers in the shader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out my shader code was fine and my mind was going in the completely opposite direction. The problem was that I was loading in int values as a vertex array attributes. This isn't handled to well by the GPU and any value over 0 was converted to some (seemingly) random number which caused only the index 0 to work, giving my the illusion that I was loading up my values incorrectly.